# Working with miniconda/anaconda without using virtual environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm new to this things called virtual environments and I only have a small history with programming (Fortran then Python). I'm trying to figure this out and I've been reading the [conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/). My main question at the moment is: ***what happens when I use the miniconda version of python without being inside a virtual environment?***

I've figured out a couple of things but I'd like to know if I truly understand this, so if anyone can say: *yes that's right*, or, *that's not quite true*, or *son, you're totally lost here* (in which case maybe point me in the right direction?) thanks in advance!

I understand, so far, that my path now has the miniconda3 directory listed first (I've added `PATH="/home/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` to my .bashrc file), so when I use python from my terminal then, the miniconda python is found first. I also believe (not sure) that for any other program that I have installed, I need to specify where this python is (`miniconda3/bin/python`**???**).

I also noticed that if I install any package (let's say `conda install numpy`), then that package is available for use, because it got installed within the "base" virtual environment, then I also have access to that package within other virtual environments without having installed it specifically for those environments.
**But** if I do `conda activate base` and then `conda install numpy`, I do have access to numpy from outside any virtual environment, but I do not have access from any other virtual environment. So, why is that different?

Thanks in advance for any insight into this confusing world.

Cheers!

Comment: *"because it got installed within the "base" virtual environment, then I also have access to that package within other virtual environments without having installed it specifically for those environments"*
That sounds wrong, the virtual environments should be isolated from the base an each other. Maybe when you are creating a new virtual environment, you are telling it to inherit all the packages from the base? that's a bad idea though. You should treat them as isolated environments that are totally separate from one another.

Comment: Conda is itself a way to create and work in a virtual environment. So when you activate the environment and type `which python` it shows the link to the python you are using at present.

Comment: @Dan I'm very new, and I'm not telling anything to my created virtual environments (I just do "conda create -n myenv". Now I've keep practicing and I noticed that if a create a new environment in a custom directory (using "conda create -p ./myenv"), then my new virtual environment is completely blank, with no packages whatsoever, not even python ("which python" gives "/usr/bin/python").